# Java: package does not exist

Tags: java

I am in the directory: E:\stuff\Java>

I created a package A:

```
package pack;

public class A
{
    public void methodA(){
        System.out.println("MethodA");
    }
}
```

To compile I have used the following statement:

```
javac -d . A.java
```

So a folder with the name pack has been created which contains A.class.
Then i tried to import this package in another program:

```
import pack.A;

    class B
    {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            A a = new A();
            a.methodA();
        }
    }
```

When i try to compile this code:

```
javac B.java
```

I get the following error:

```
   B.java:1: error: package pack does not exist
import pack.A;
           ^
B.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                A a = new A();
                ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
B.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                A a = new A();
                          ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
3 errors
```

I don't understand why the code fails to run. My B.java file and pack are in the same folder.

Can someone please explain the error in this code??

Comment: Add `pack.A` to the classpath when compiling `B`.

Comment: I tried this on my computer, and everything compiled just fine. Are you sure that `B.java` and `pack` are in the same folder, and `A.java` is in `pack`?

Comment: Did you use java -d ./ B.java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your error it looks like your "other program" `B.java` is not in the same directory (E:\stuff\Java) of 'A.java'. This means that when you try to compile `B.java` the compiler does not know where to find class `pack.A`. To "make A visible" you must add `pack.A` to your classpath, which means compiling with:

```
javac -cp ".;<path_to_add>" B.java
```

In your case `<path_to_add>` should be `E:\stuff\Java`. This sets your classpath to not only the current directory (`.`) but also the directory where your `pack` package is.

To run your program you again have to add `pack.A` to you class path:

```
java -cp ".;<path_to_add>" B
```

Where again `<path_to_add>` should be `E:\stuff\Java`.

Here I am assuming you are using windows. On Unix the `-cp` option as a slightly different syntax: `-cp ".:<path_to_add>"` where the `;` has been replaced by `:`.

Comment: My B.java file is actually in the same directory as my package(pack) i.e E:\stuff\Java.  However it worked when i tried your way. Thank you very much for clearing my doubt.
You can also write :
     set classpath=E:\stuff\Java
and run your code normally to get the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the following command to compile the program on windows :

```
 javac -cp "<path of the package folder>" file_name.java
```

And the command to execute the program :

```
java -cp "<path of the package folder>" file_name
```