# Java: Error: package does not exist

Tags: java, package

I've looked everywhere and I seemingly tried everything. I can't get rid of this error. First, my code. The directory in my computer matches the one in the GitHub link, replacing Pset2:/ with W:/, here is all the code:

https://github.com/MichaelGordonII/JavaCS50/tree/master/pset2

In command prompt I use the following command: 
`W:/Mario/src:>javac -cp w:/Mario/src/output Mario.java`
This gets me the error. I have tried other tags with the same results. I've even tried IntelliJ IDEA 15 Community and it always says I don't have an SDK. I've beat my head on a wall enough, I just need someone else's eyes.

EDIT: Error message:

```
W:/Mario/src>javac mario.java
mario.java:5: error: package w.mario.src.output does not exist
import w.mario.src.output.OuputToFile;
                         ^
mario.java:6: error: package w.mario.src.output does not exist
import w.mario.src.output.OutputToConsole
                         ^
mario.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
OutputType outputCommand = (desiredOutputType.equals("textfile")) ? new OuputToFile() : new OutputToConsole();
^
mario.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
OutputType outputCommand = (desiredOutputType.equals("textfile")) ? new OuputToFile() : new OutputToConsole();
                                                                        ^
symbol: class OutputToFile
location: class Mario

mario.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
OutputType outputCommand = (desiredOutputType.equals("textfile")) ? new OuputToFile() : new OutputToConsole();
                                                                                            ^
symbol: class OutputToConsole
location: class Mario
5 errors
```

Comment: Try to post the error

Comment: You need to change the name of your package.  It shouldn't reference from root, but be a relative path to your project's `src` folder.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186457/java-package-does-not-exist) might be helpful.

Comment: added error message. and so change package name to output?

Comment: Change the package name to something that makes sense to the whole project, like `mario`. Then make sure the relative folder structure inside `src` mimics the package name.

Comment: Forgive me if this sounds stupid, but isn't that what I did with output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either missing one of these : JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME. Look at this [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

Comment: Reading this link, I found that I don't have a c:/program files (x86)/Java directory. Uninstalling and reinstalling IDEA to see if that installs it.

Comment: Okay I found my issue with IntelliJ at least. The Java directory is in Program Files not Program Files (x86). That is where my JDK is.